# WordPress won't stay logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I moved my WordPress install from a development server to a freshly installed CentOS Apache 2.2 PHP 5.3 server.  Initially, everything was working well.  Logging in wasn't a problem, but then I noticed after logging in as a WordPress user and loading a new page I would be logged out.

What PHP settings do I need to have enabled, or are there any other considerations, when using a fresh server for WordPress that would make users not able to stay logged in (almost like the session isn't saving them)?

**edit**

It seems like the server isn't logging people in, but is reading the $_POST variable, so why would WordPress not save logging in?

Comment: maybe the apache user doesn't have permissions to write in session files (apache or the user you selected for your blog)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was looking at `output_buffer`. When this was off, the wp functions couldn't save to the session because something was already writing to the header.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find any other support so I wanted to leave it here (and apparently it takes two days before you can accept your own answer).